# Modifiying a GET request before it goes into the URL

Tags: php, get

Here's what I am trying to do, say the user enters data into an input and submits it. I want to be able to modify the data that was submitted before it goes into the URL. So say for this instance I want to add a few letters at the end of the string that is submitted when it is submitted.

Comment: @AurelBílý How do you think I should go about doing it in javascript?

Comment: Please see answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to make sure a different URL is submitted than what the form fields specify, you need to modify the field with Javascript, e.g. by listening on the `submit` event.

Otherwise, if you don't mind doing two requests, you can use PHP to redirect the client to a different URL with modified parameters.

Also – why do you want this? Modifying URL parameters before / after form submission is not something that websites generally do.

Comment: Basically keeping the information hidden, but I need to use the GET action. So.

Comment: What information? Please don't use anything like this for anything sensitive, e.g. user / password combinations. If you want to make sure information is not transmitted over the network in cleartext, use HTTPS.

Comment: Oh gosh no, I am doing stuff with a web proxy. So it would just be urls